# find pairs of numbers where cube is equal to square

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

We are given a number N and we have to find pairs i and j where i^3=j^2

For example, let N=50 so for this we will have 3 pairs (1,1),(4,8),(9,27)
basically, we have to find pairs where the cube of one number is the same as the square of the other number in a given pair

the constraint is

- 1<=N<10^6
- 1<=i,j<N

Naive approach use 2 for loops iterate through each element and get those pairs where cube is equal to sum time complexity is O(n*2)

```
def get_pair(N):
    for i in range(1,N):
        for j in range(1,N):
            if i*i*i==j*j:
                print(i,j)
N=50
get_pair(N)
```

what will be an optimal way to solve this problem with a better time complexity?

Comment: (1,1) violates 1<i,j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're working with integers, if there exists some number M = i^3 = j^2 for i and j between 1 and N, then that means there exists a k such that M = k^6. To find i and j, simply compare the representations of M:

(1) M = k^6 = i^3 = (k^2)^3 therefore i = k^2

(2) M = k^6 = j^2 = (k^3)^2 therefore j = k^3

Since j is always greater than or equal to i, you only need to check if 1 < k^3 < N. In other words, k should be less than the cube root of N.

| k | M = k^6 | i = k^2 | j = k^3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 64 | 4 | 8 |
| 3 | 729 | 9 | 27 |
| 4 | 4,096 | 16 | 64 |
| 5 | 15,625 | 25 | 125 |
| 6 | 46,656 | 36 | 216 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 97 | 8.329x10^11 | 9409 | 912,673 |
| 98 | 8.858x10^11 | 9604 | 941,192 |
| 99 | 9.415x10^11 | 9801 | 970,299 |

Note that 100 isn't a valid candidate for k because that would make j *less than or equal to* N instead of *strictly less than* N (if we're going with N = 10^6).

So to get the list of tuples that satisfy your problem, find the values of k such that 1 < k^3 < N and return its square and cube in a tuple.

```py
import math
from typing import List, Tuple

N: int = 10**6
pairs: List[Tuple[int, int]] = [(k * k, k * k * k) for k in range(2, math.ceil(N**(1 / 3)))]
print(pairs)
```

This is a list comprehension, a shorthand for a for-loop.

I'm basically asking Python to generate a list of tuples over an index k that falls in the range defined as `range(2, math.ceil(N**(1 / 3))`. That range is exactly the first column of the table above.

Then, for every k in that range I make a tuple of which the first item is k^2 and the second item is k^3, just like the last two columns of the table.

Also threw in the `typing` library in there for good measure. Clear code is good code, even for something as small as this. Python can figure out that `pairs` is a list of tuples without anyone telling it, but this way I've explicitly enforced that variable to be a list of tuples to avoid any confusion when someone tries to give it a different value or isn't sure what the variable contains.

Comment: I'm not redefining anything, N is constrained between 1 and 10^6.

Comment: The range is not until N^(1/6).

Comment: @YvesDaoust it isn't? What other values would you need to check then?

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah I see what you mean now

Comment: @KellyBundy there you go, hope it's clearer now

Comment: @JansthcirlU: until M:=N^(1/3). Because M³, M² ≤N.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's confusing, as they already defined M as something else.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ah I see, I missed the i and j constraint of the question, will edit

Comment: @KellyBundy kindly undo your edit and read the full sentence.

Comment: @KellyBundy if you want to change it to "good code is clear code" go right ahead, but I think the way I wrote it also gets the message across given the context

Comment: Great answer; it might be worth explaining why the first sentence is true for people with less math background, especially since the proof is fairly short.

Comment: @kcsquared to be very honest, I just went in with my gut feeling that if M is an integer that has a cube root and a square root, then it must have a sixth root, which is not very rigorous...

Answer (score 0):

Another naive approach could be to use the "basic" values ?

```
def get_pair(N):
    for i in range(N):
        if(i**3 > MAX):
            break    # Limit to the max you want, and i**3 > i**2 if i > 1

        print(i**2, i**3)
```

Time complexity seems to be O(n) (Not an expert, so correct me if i'm wrong)

This is made so that the first element cubed == second element squared:

```
first = a^2
second = a^3

first^3 = a^(2*3) = a^6
second^2 = a^(3*2) = a^6
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with one loop (and minimal iterations) if you know that that pairs `(x, y)` are always `y = x * i`, this means you can use:

```
def get_pair(N):
    i = 1
    a = 1
    while a * i < N:
        b = a * i
        print(a,b)
        i += 1
        a = i**2

N=50
get_pair(N)
```

This gets all 3 pairs:

```
1 1
4 8
9 27
```

In only 3 total iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itertool's `combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) function.

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as combinations

def get_pair(N):
    for i, j in combinations(range(1,N), 2):
        if i*i*i==j*j:
            print(i,j)
N=50
get_pair(N)
```